# How to design a map that has O(1) for get, set, remove and generateRandomValue?

Tags: data-structures

Say we already have a perfectMap that has O(1) for get(k), set(k, v), remove(k), how to design a map that has O(1) for get(k), set(k, v), remove(k) and generateRandomValue() which randomly generates a value of all the values stored in the map?

I tried sets, linked lists but still have no clue.

Comment: Please describe the problem more precisely.